# Combinatorics problem: How many ways this row can be filled?

Tags: combinatorics

> A row measuring $N$ units in length has $M$ red blocks with a
> length of one unit placed on it, such that any two red blocks
> are separated by at least
> one grey square. How many ways are there to fill the row?

To give you some visual aid, I will provide several examples.

Row length($N$) = $4$, number of blocks($M$) = $2$

[image]

There are $3$ ways to fill row above.

$N = 6, M = 2$

[image]

There are $6$ ways to fill row above.

And the last one:

$N = 7, M = 3$

[image]

There are $10$ ways to fill row above.

Now, what I want is to derive general formula that will calculate number of ways I can fill row given arbitrary $N$ (row length) and $M$ (number of red blocks)

After making several attempts, the formulas I end up with contain *a lot* of summation signs, and the more number of blocks there are, the more summation signs. Yet I want $1$ formula that will work for any scenario. Is it possible to derive such formula?

Comment: Hint: If we assume the last block is not red, then every red block is followed by a grey block.  Can you count them under this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly we need $N\geqslant 2M-1$, otherwise there are not enough grey blocks.

Place the $M$ red blocks in a row, and interlace $M-1$ grey blocks between every two so that you have an alternating pattern:
$${\color{red} R}{\color{gray} G}{\color{red} R}{\color{gray} G}\cdots{\color{gray} G}{\color{red} R}$$
Now you can insert the remaining $N-2M+1$ grey blocks in any of these spaces:
$$\,\_\,{\color{red} R}\,\_\,{\color{gray} G}{\color{red} R}\,\_\,{\color{gray} G}\cdots{\color{red} R}\,\_\,{\color{gray} G}{\color{red} R}\,\_\,$$
There are $M+1$ such spaces (to the right of each $\color{red}R$, plus the one at the front). We can choose were to put the grey blocks by "choosing" these spaces (multiple times if we wish). So we are choosing with repetition allowed, and order of choice not important. The number of ways this can be done is $\big(\!\binom{M+1}{N-2M+1}\!\big)=\boxed{\binom{N-M+1}{M}}$.

This agrees with your examples:

[image]

---

$\left(\!\binom nk\!\right)$ denotes the number of choosing $k$ out of $n$ things with repetition allowed, and order not important; it is given by $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$. This is called [*multichoose*](http://multichoose.net/).

The Wikipedia article on [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is also helpful to understand this concept, there is a [Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTCScjoPymA) on YouTube too.

Answer (score 1):

Each red block except the one at the end (if there is one) must have a gray block to its right.  Attach a gray block to all the red ones except the last (if there is one) making red/gray blocks.  If there is a red block at the right end you have $M-1$ red/gray blocks and $N-2M+1$ single gray blocks to put in order.  There are $N-M \choose M-1$ ways to do that because you choose the positions of the red/gray blocks.  If there is not a red block at the end you have $M$ red/gray blocks and $N-2M$ single gray blocks so there are $N-M \choose M$ orders.  Add these up and you are done.

Comment: I don't think this is right, $\binom{10-3}{3-1}+\binom{10-3}{3}=56\neq 10$.

Comment: @LukeCollins But the last example given in the OP (the one with $10$ possibilities) doesn't have $N=10$, it has $N=7$.

Comment: @Arthur You are correct, I misread! I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

There are N rows and M Red blocks. That means there are ( N - M )  grey blocks. 
All grey can be arranged in 1 way there between fray and including ends there are ( N - M + 1) places of which select any M and put Red blocks there. Hence answer will be $  \binom{N-M+1}{M}   $

Answer (score 1):

If you add one more gray block on the right side, then your problem becomes that of ordering $N+1-M$ blocks, $M$ of which are 2 wide, with a red on the left and a gray on the right, $N+1-2M$ of them which are just 1 gray wide. This can be done in $\binom{N+1-M}{M}$ ways. Then just chop off the rightmost gray block once you're done arranging.